# Windows 10 Photos App Why I Can't Add new folder?

Tags: windows-10, photos

So I can't add folders to my Windows Photo App, I click on Add folder and it does nothing, by running it on another pc I can see it should show a list of recommended folders but the button to add folder does nothing at all.

I have tried all the following: Uninstalled it, Installed, Repair and Reset the app, run the troubleshooter, run a bunch of commands, found a weird registry and deleted it (Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\StorageLibrary\ChangeTracking\Microsoft.Windows.Photos_8wekyb3d8bbwe\1) which contained a folder path for the app, then I put it back, changed all ownership of the windows apps folder, manually deleted the app folders, went to appsettings local and deleted everything that had some semblance of having to do with photos, nothing has worked so far. I've searched a lot on google and everyone who has had this issue has been unable to fix it until they reinstal the whole OS. And that is just not an option for me.

Has anyone ever encountered this?

Answer (score 1):

There is another way to add a folder to Windows Photos App.

1. Press <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> to open the Run box.
2. Paste this inside the box exactly as is:

   `%UserProfile%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Libraries`
3. Click **OK** to open the Windows libraries.
4. Right click **Pictures** library and select **Properties**.
5. In the Properties window, on the Library tab, click the **Add...** button.
6. Select the folder you want to add to your Windows Photos App.